# How to PreRunning preloading pretesting custom/stock ROM in android virtual machine on mobile device

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, android-emulator, stock-rom, virtualbox

**Question How to PreRunning  preloading pretesting  custom/stock  ROM in android virtual machine on  mobile device**

I Have many custom android custom rom (android 6,7,8,9,10,11) availabale for my device  i want to check all roms and test their features (mainly adoptable storage or move app to sd and permission security features) and weather it's not a buggy or problematic rom before installing or flashing is there any app available which can load the android on virtual machine virtual box or android emulator on mobile device (not on pc computer)

After google I founded a link  quesion in the forum and answered by  ash-ish which link and aswer I pasted below stating how to virtually load the custom rom through multi ROM app

Before trying I just want to confirm and have following queries in mind

**MY queries**

Q1. Is multiboot app install multiple roms or single rom

Q2. Does multiboot app safe and authenticated

Q3. Does multiboot app really load virtually  the custom ROM or it  writes or install roms to the internal memory or does it touches any rom partitions

Q4 does chances to brick the mobile if there is some buggy or corrupt custom rom image then can I corrupt the original firmware of mobile device while loading virtually

Q5. Can later multiboot app be uninstalled and remove do it leave any leftovers in rom.. if I take NANDROID backup of recovery system userdata and boot partition through twrp ir adb pull can I r cover back the mobile or recover from bricked stage of mobile device

Q6. As the suggestion in the following link answer for multiboot is for samsung galaxy edge will it work on all android mobile will it work on my lyf water 7 device

Q7. Any more advice opinion suggestion expert advice

**My findings**

**Android emulator**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985384/run-custom-rom-on-android-emulator

**Multiboot app**

[Running a stock or custom ROM in a virtual machine on Android⠀](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126407/running-a-stock-or-custom-rom-in-a-virtual-machine-on-android)

> Question Running a stock or custom ROM in a virtual machine on Android⠀
> android-emulator samsung-galaxy-s-6 virtualbox
> Can I run a virtual Android machine on my Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge? Or maybe can I run a custom ROM without flashing stock?

**Answered by Ash-Ishh**

> Part 1: Using Multiple ROMs without flashing again and again

> App required: MultiRom
> Introduction:

> MultiRom powerful utility that installs itself into your Custom Recovery.

> First Step: "BACKUP" It is recomended to make a nandroid backup of your current ROM in case something goes wrong you can just restore it.

> Procedure:

> Once you have installed MultiRom open up the app. MultiRom will ask for Root Access. After granting it, you should see Multirom and its current version, the recovery that is required to manage Multirom with, and the MultiRom Kernel (Kexec-hardboot patch)

> Just tick all 3 boxes to install Multirom, the recovery patch, and the kernel. Once it’s finished installing, MultiRom Manager should prompt you to reboot into Recovery to complete the installation. Once you’ve entered the Custom recovery, it should complete the installation and will soon reboot itself.

> A message will appear saying something similar like the device will boot into the internal rom in 5 seconds, unless you click cancel. You haven’t installed another Rom into MultiRom yet, so you should only see one option to boot into, and that should say Internal. Internal is pretty much your current Rom, or whatever you were using before installing Multirom. If you do not click cancel, your device will boot into the Internal Rom by default, so click cancel in the event you decide to boot into a different Rom.

> Now, in order for you to boot into a different Rom, first you have to download the different Custom Roms you want.

> ONLY DOWNLOAD THE CUSTOM ROM THAT’S SUPPORTED BY YOUR DEVICE

> Note that once you install your Custom Rom, Google Apps and Services will not be installed on it, so you will have to download something called GAPPS (Google Apps) for the respective Android version. so now download the GAPPS zip file.

> Once you are back into your device’s Stock Rom, we will be using TWRP Recovery, as it is the default Custom recovery supported by MultiRom. Once you are in TWRP, click advanced. You should see a new option called MultiRom. Click that, and you can configure settings, as well as install your Custom Rom to boot from.

> Assuming you now have your Custom Rom downloaded on your device,click “Add Rom.” You will see many settings on the screen. For Choose ROM type, leave it by default, which is Android. Share Roms with Internal ROM, just leave that as don’t share. You can also see where the Custom Rom will be installed to. By default it will list your internal memory, but if you have an SD card, or even a USB Flash drive that is plugged into your device VIA OTG cable, it will be listed there as well. So just pick the destination of where you want your Custom Rom to be installed/saved on.

> Click next, and select your source of installing your custom Rom. 3 Options will appear, which include Zip File, Backup, and ADB Sideload. You should have downloaded your Custom Rom earlier in for form of a .zip file, so just select ZIP File. Next, you will navigate to the place where you downloaded your Custom Rom, which most likely will be located in your Downloads folder. So find that and select it. Once you have it selected, you will reach a page where it shows you to confirm flash. So swipe the bar to confirm the Flash, or installation of your Custom Rom, and let it install on its own. Once the installation has ended, do not be so quick as to click reboot.

> Click the back button on the bottom right hand side, and head over to the List Roms option from earlier. Then, click on the Rom that you just installed, and click Flash Zip, which will flash the Zip file for that individual Rom. Now, flash Google’s apps and services that you have downloaded now Reboot>system.

> You should be prompted with the same interface as earlier when you installed MultiRom where it asks you which Rom you want to boot into. Click Cancel, as we do not want to boot into our internal rom. Now you should see your brand new installed Custom Rom name listed in the Boot options. Click on that, and confirm you want to boot into it.

> Now the Custom Rom’s default boot animation should appear, so that indicates you’ve done everything right. Note that this simulates the process of a brand new fresh operating system being booted up for the first time, so the boot process should take a while longer, just wait a few minutes until you reach the device setup screen.

> In the case that you want to uninstall MultiRom, just boot back into your Internal rom and head over to the Multirom Manager app, and click on the big trash can at the top right corner, as this just means the removal and deletion of MultiRom. Click on confirm delete, and follow the on-screen instructions for uninstallation.

Comment: you don't have enough disk space for multiboot. Furthermore it's less painful to flash custom ROM instead of trying to get multiboot working. embedded device is not PC. multiROM is outdated and does not support any if your devices